# Multiple Categories in DB

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a page where you can select a category link and then it will show the categories under that category kinda like steps going downward. I want to do my db table like this

```
table [categories]
pk categoryID
categoryName
parentID
level
```

that parentID links itself back to the categoryID. Is there any tutorials out there that shows this demonstration I haven't found any. Or is there a better way todo this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your table up for a recursive one-to-many relationship, like this making a few assumptions about data types):

```
CREATE TABLE [Categories]
(
    CategoryID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ParentCategoryID int NULL,
    -- Level field is not needed; can be dynamically determined

    CONSTRAINT FK_Child_to_Parent 
        FOREIGN KEY (ParentCategoryID)
            REFERENCES [Categories] (CategoryID)    

)
```

In order to query this table in general, you need to use a self-join, like this (note the from/join; this is the part you will re-use):

```
select child.*, parent.*
from Categories child
join Categories parent on child.ParentCategoryID = parent.CategoryID
```

You can tell when you are looking at a parent category because the value for `ParentCategoryID` will be `NULL`.  To answer your question of how to get child categories for your page given a parent ID, you can use this:

```
select child.CategoryID, child.CategoryName
from Categories child 
join Categories parent on child.ParentCategoryID = parent.CategoryID
where parent.ParentCategoryID = [some value]
```

There are tons of tutorials/designs out there if you Google "recursive database table" or related terms; for starters, here is one (picked at random):http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php

Comment: I don't know .net 4.0 well just learning but what I want to accomplish is url routing with multiple categories in the url eg. www.something.com/clothing/mens/somepage.aspx the hard part to all this is managing it on the adminstration side. I'd need to have an insert textbox with a listbox and form next to it to update the selected Item and with the selected item create another select box of sub categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL 2005+ you can use a SQL recursive common table expression (CTE).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/